# Porque negativar uma pergunta que está (aparentemente) correta?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica

Assim, a gente faz um texto explicando, cola o código, e a pessoa negativa a pergunta e vai embora, sem deixar comentário e nem resposta.

Neste caso, a minha pergunta apresenta algum quesito de ser negativada?

Quem puder, da uma olhada e me fale o que tem de errado para não fazer de novo, pois somos uma comunidade e precisamos nos ajudar.

Pergunta: [Como desabilitar o evento do botão direito do mouse no Angular 7?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/392558/como-desabilitar-o-evento-do-bot%C3%A3o-direito-do-mouse-no-angular-7)

Agradeço já a quem puder ajudar.

Comment: Relevantes: [Voto negativo sem justificativa é válido?](/questions/6386/70) e [Votos negativos em uma pergunta](/questions/652/70) - Não dá para falar em nome de quem negativou, mas em princípio se der um "hover" na seta do downvote são apresentadas as possibilidades mais plausíveis: _"Esta pergunta não mostra nenhum esforço de pesquisa; ela não é clara ou não é útil"_ (o que não quer dizer que seja o caso da sua pergunta, mas pode ser). Considerando que o voto é de foro pessoal de quem vota, melhor se apegar ao score geral do post do que a um ou outro voto específico.

Comment: Sobre a sua pergunta, sinceramente eu acho que daria para explicar melhor a dificuldade e o resultado que quer obter, mas como não uso typescript, vou deixar os comentários sobre o teor e eventuais votos a critério de outros colegas. Pelo título sua pergunta aqui no meta seria uma duplicata, mas como está tratando de perguntar sobre a postagem específica acrescentei a tag relevante.

Comment: Eu entendo que se a pergunta é mal explicada ou falta partes ela tende a ser negativada, e também já tinha visto que qualquer usuário pode negativar uma pergunta sem qualquer justificativa (ao meu ver, é um erro, pois não acrescenta em nada e o usuário que fez a pergunta fica no limbo, sem entender).
Quando fiz essa pergunta no meta, a minha pergunta tinha apenas 4 visitas e um voto negativo, no momento que faço esse comentário, ela está com 0 votos (alguém deu voto positivo).

Comment: Sobre achar que permitir o voto sem justificativa é um erro, sugiro que leia [este FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357437) (infelizmente só tem em inglês), que explica os motivos de ser assim. Eu entendo o seu lado, pois é chato receber negativos sem saber porquê, mas também entendo os pontos explicados no FAQ. No fim, parece-me que a posição oficial é a de não mudar esse funcionamento...

Comment: Eu entendo a parte de se preocupar com perseguição com que faz downvote, mas do contrário, desanima os membros novos (like me :] ) de continuar a fazer perguntas. Por exemplo, eu gasto meu tempo fazendo comentários e respondendo perguntas simples para ganhar pontos de reputação, fazer perguntas é o meio mais rápido, mas infelizmente tem um pessoal que não quer colaborar com a comunidade. Enfim, infelizmente não podemos fazer nada a respeito, já que a empresa quer assim e acha que isso é melhor. Poderiam deixar um comentário anônimo ao usuário, mas, enfim...

Comment: Um motivo (pouco provável) é que sua pergunta não faz sentido, desabilitar o menu do _rigth click_? Prejudica UX, tem muitos usuários que usa essas opções pra recarregar a página, voltar e avançar, no Chrome tem a opção de tradução, etc. Pessoalmente não negativaria, apesar de acreditar nisto, mas outros podem ter feito isso

Comment: Mas isso é não entender o motivo do usuário estar perguntando, por exemplo, na pergunta, o sistema não deve permitir que o usuário copie o texto ou imprima. Então estava pensando em todas as formas de evitar isso, o que inclui o botão direito do mouse. Agora já me falaram que posso, simplesmente, esconder o Body quando capturar esse evento.

Comment: Queria perguntar algo parecido, tive uma duvida técnica quanto a algo e alguem negativou a pergunta, penso que é tão difícil adicionar um simples "comentário", precisa de muito conhecimento e reputação, mas para negativar alguém é bem simples, creio que para negativar uma pergunta técnica alguém deveria ter pelo menos uma reputação necessária pra isso, estou apenas comentando, pois estou aprendendo ainda.
Não sei por exemplo porque alguém negativou ela, sem nem ter dado explicação, será que foi por causa de uma edição de algumas virgulas?

@Bacco poderia me ajudar? gostaria de saber mais

Comment: Queria entender, não por ego, mas pra melhorar se fosse o caso, pois eu realmente necessito de ajuda na solução de alguns problemas!

Comment: Eu particularmente acho _perca_ de tempo tentar impedir usuários de copiar texto da página, ver o código-fonte etc etc. É impossível evitar isso. Vc pode até dificultar para usuários leigos, mas se o usuário _quer porque quer_ copiar um texto (longo, pq se for curto ele até irá copiar digitando) ou algo da página, ele irá encontrar meios pra isso, e não é difícil, seja pesquisando no Google ou consultando um amigo nerd.[...]

Comment: [...] Mas, claro, a pergunta em si não deveria ser analisada por esse escopo, cada um faz o que quer e acha direito com o que está desenvolvendo. Mas, cara, receber voto negativo não é o fim do mundo. Eu vejo muito mais _injustiça_ e mal uso de votos com votos positivos do que com negativos. Respostas ruins com códigos ruins sendo supervalorizados recebendo vários votos `+`. Então, não se sabe quem está por trás (ou melhor, em frente) de um monitor pq há o anonimato, mas estou certo de q usuários que usam essa prerrogativa de anonimato para fazer baboseira, não duram mt tempo no site.

Comment: O triste é perder pontos por causa desses usuários, a gente que é novo no site, quer conseguir todos os privilégios para ser mais participativos e tal, e ai vem um qualquer e faz isso. Enfim, só pra lembrar que isso desanima os novos usuários, como eu.